# Copy Class style to another element without changing it's class

Tags: javascript, html, css

The story is long and a painful but in short

I have element like :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-add-cart">Add to cart</button>
```

And I want it to look like :

```
<a href="#" class="dc_bevel_button green">Green Button</a>
```

That is for specific view and i should not to change the class since it's used for quite few things. 
Is it a way just to pass the style to it  with javascript.

Comment: does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can use `addClass`, something like this -:

```
var element = document.getElementById("yourSelectorForButton");
element.removeAttribute("class");
element.classList.add("dc_bevel_button green");
```

Also if you don't wan't to add the class directly we can add style as well -:

```
document.getElementById("yourSelectorForButton").style = "copy paste style from dc_bevel_button green";
```

Comment: Sorry for the late post i was off couple of days but it didn't work if i add a class without removing the old one the style stay the same. And the style for the dc button is ever changin.

Comment: @HristoAlexsiev Then add this line before adding your class as shown in above edited answer -:: `document.getElementById("yourSelectorForButton").removeAttribute("class");`

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, You are trying to copy the styles of **btn btn-lg btn-add-cart** to **dc_bevel_button**. If so then you have 3 options

1. Copy the styles manually
2. If you are using preprocessor like SASS then you can extend the original class with your own class [Example Link](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend)

3, If you are looking for runtime option then you are probably looking for **getComputedStyle** [Example - How to use getComputedStyle](https://zellwk.com/blog/css-values-in-js/)